# Is there a website that has sound clips with written transcription for various dialects?

Tags: topolect

My specific use case is I want to hear how 私 is pronounced in Hunanese, but I remember coming across a website a few years ago with lots of speech recordings in various Chinese dialects with written character transcriptions that could be searched. Does anyone know of a website like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the website you came across was Phonemica? https://phonemica.net/

It contains recordings from various dialects and has a search function: https://phonemica.net/search

Comment: Thank you, that was the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

you may try the 漢語多功能字庫, maintained by chinese university of hong kong; that, it has a section “other dialects” (其他方言讀音)

choose the “長沙”, “私” is entry 665; or, entry 602 in “湘潭” there’s link to the sound file

https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/dialectIndex.php?point=F

https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/dialectIndex.php?point=G

i mentioned “may” is, the link does not work on a ios device in lockdown mode , but i guess that it should work on other platforms, or less privacy concerned scenario

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/) has fairly good written records for [Xiang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiang_Chinese).

Take [私](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A7%81) for instance

> • [Xiang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiang_Chinese)
> ‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎• ([Changsha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changsha_dialect))
> ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎  ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎  ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ • [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Chinese/Xiang): sr1
> ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎  ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎  ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ • Sinological [IPA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:International_Phonetic_Alphabet) ([key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changsha_dialect)): /sz̩³³/